# No /usr/sbin/vsftpd found running; none killed

Tags: tftp

I tried to install and use a simples FTP server on my Pi.

I fallow [this](http://workshop.botter.ventures/2013/08/27/how-to-setup-an-ftp-server-with-vsftpd-on-raspberry-pi/) tutorial, but not success.

When I type `service vsftpd restart` it returns for me

```
     Stopping FTP server: No /usr/sbin/vsftpd found running; none killed.
      vsftpd.
     /etc/vsftpd.conf: listen disabled - service will not start
```

Somebody know a tutorial for I create a simples FTP server. (can be an advanced too)

Thanks in advanced.

Comment: What are you actually trying to achieve? You can already use a FTP client to connect to the Pi.

Comment: Yes, I want to make my PI in a FTP server and shared files, upload, downloads, etc

Comment: There is already FTP. Just connect from any client.

Comment: I can't. When I trying to ser in my firefox gives error, ou if I use filezilla it didn't Connect

Comment: `cat /etc/services | grep ftp` should show if `ftp` is running

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This thread may be interesting to you: https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=36&t=35661

It says: sftp is already available on your Pi because it is part of the ssh daemon. To get filezilla to connect, change the protocol from ftp to sftp and/or change port number to 22.

If you really do need an ftp server, try this: http://www.pibeginners.com/ftp-server/
It says you simply need to run
`sudo apt-get install proftpd` and choose standalone mode.

For configuring it to allow anonymous ftp, take a look here: 
http://www.proftpd.org/docs/howto/ConfigFile.html
In summary - you need to add an `<anonymous>` section to the `/etc/proftpd/proftpd.conf` file.

Comment: `sftp` is nothing more than transfering files via `ssh`

Comment: @Flash Thunder It is, but its more subtle than that. `sftp` presents an interface which is similar to `ftp`, which is different from the interface provided by `scp` which is also provided by the ssh daemon. Both could be considered to be "transferring files by ssh" but the OP mentioned filezilla and firefox which implied he needed an ftp style interface.

Comment: but it's part of `ssh` implementation... even the name tells it: `sftp` = `SSH File Transfer Protocol` ... `scp` is like... older version of `sftp` :-)

Comment: @Flash Thunder Yes - I think we both agree that it's provided by the ssh daemon.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply. I want to acess ftp server Pi from a browser like this pic https://vichhaiy.files.wordpress.com/2013/05/052313_0325_setupftpser1.png?w=593

Comment: It sounds like you want anonymous ftp setup.  I'll add that to the answer.

Comment: Yes, this proftpd run. But whats is the difference in proftpd for vsftpd?

Comment: I founded a link http://hilpisch.com/rpi/01_ftp_server.html it is very helpful.